# why is my javascript passing the wrong information?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a webpage that is an invoice that contains 2 table that contains a job and it's associated tasks.  I populating the table with mysql data using node.js.

There are also 4 iframes used to display timers for tasks.
I have a Javascript function that checks if an iframe has been loaded and made visible if not then the timer is loaded into the iframe if so check the next and so on till all 4 have been checked.  The function exits once it has loaded an iframe so only 1 iframe loads at a time.

this works fine except that no matter which task I click on to move to the timer the first item in the table is loaded.  In other words if there are 5 tasks listed in a table the first item is always the one that loads regardless of which one I choose.

this is the html

```
<div style='position:absolute;left:8px;top:88px;width:1000px;'>

<table align='left' border='1' ; style='font-size:16px;width:79%'>
 <tr>
   <th align='left'  style='background-color: #00b0e6;'><%= job1 %></th>
   <th align='center'  style='background-color: #00b0e6;'></th>
   <th align='center' style='background-color: #00b0e6;'> Employee </th>
   <th align='center' style='background-color: #00b0e6;'> Status </th>
   <th align='center' style='background-color: #00b0e6;'> Charges </th>
 </tr>

<%
 for (var i in taskrows) {
   if (taskrows[i].JobID == jb1){
   var task = taskrows[i].Task;
   var emp = taskrows[i].Employee;
   var status = taskrows[i].Status;
   var extended = "$"+taskrows[i].Extended.toFixed([2]);
   var id = taskrows[i].ID;
   var instid = rows[0].InstID

%>

<tr>
  <td width='45%'><%= task %></td>
  <td width='2%'><form id='form1' ><input type='hidden' name='id' value=<%= id %>/><input type='hidden' name='instid' value=<%= instid %>/><input type='button' id="11" name='submit-btn'  src='images/clock.jpg' width='30' height='20' value='submit' onClick='moveBench();' /></form></td>
  <td align='center' width='15%'><%= emp %></td>
  <td align='center' width='20%'><%= status %></td>
  <td align='center' width='10%'><%= extended %></td>
  <td width='35%'></td></tr>
<%}
}%>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the javascript function

```
function checkTimer(){
  var ben = parent.document.getElementById('bench').style.height = "340px";
  var inv = parent.document.getElementById('invoice').style.height = "340px";

  var test = document.getElementById('form1');
  var id = [
    parent.document.getElementById('timer1'),
    parent.document.getElementById('timer2'),
    parent.document.getElementById('timer3'),
    parent.document.getElementById('timer4')
];
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(!id[i].style.display){
      id[i].style.display = 'block'; id[i].style.visibility = 'visible'; value="" ;
      var a = i;
      var t = document.getElementById("form1").target='timer'+(a+1);
      var action = document.getElementById("form1").action='timer1';
      alert(document.getElementById("form1").target);
      alert(action= document.getElementById("form1").action);
      document.getElementById("form1").submit();
      return; 
      }

  }
```

Comment: I am so confused and frustrated here.  Why is my question being down voted no explianation as to what is wrong with it??????????????

Comment: Why aren't you using tables? e.g. why are you doing `<div class="tbody">` instead of `<tbody>`

Comment: I was told that forms don't work well embedded inside normal tables

Comment: I think that is misinformation and would double-check on that. Also, your question is more likely to get answered if you format your code. Your JS is difficult to read.  Lastly, your question is unclear.

Comment: You also have a `</table>` instead of a `</div>`.

Comment: Form and tables can work . Table - form /form /table. You can put a form in a td and it will work. I have done this with hidden forms before.

Comment: @Creaven yes I know I have done this before just now it seems as though the javascript does not pass the correct item?????

Comment: @sev yes I know the </div> is further down the code

Comment: Might be better to post HTML - we can't know for sure what the template output is without database connection etc...

Comment: @BillyMoon the HTML is posted

Comment: @phpnoobie well, looks to me like the source code used to derive the HTML is posted, but things like `<%= id %>` are not HTML. My point is, that in order to examine/reproduce the issue you are seeing, it is necessary to exactly the HTML produced. Otherwise, when reading the posted code, we must make a lot of assumptions that the part we can't see is working correctly, and speculate as to what it should output.

Comment: I understand that but the table information is loading properly (each row shows a differnt task etc)  Heck I don't know I think I'm about to turn this computer into a boat anchor I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem and thought I would share it.

```
<script>
  function checkTimer(){
  var ben = parent.document.getElementById('bench').style.height = "340px"; // resize the list
 var inv = parent.document.getElementById('invoice').style.height = "340px"; //Resize the Invoice

 var id = [
   parent.document.getElementById('timer1'),
   parent.document.getElementById('timer2'),
   parent.document.getElementById('timer3'),
   parent.document.getElementById('timer4')
];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  if(!id[i].style.display){
    id[i].style.display = 'block'; id[i].style.visibility = 'visible'; value="" ;
    var a = i;
    $("a").attr('target','timer'+(a+1));
    return; 
    }

  }

}
```

I used a hyperlink instead of a form and then used the javascript above to minipulate the target attribute of the hyperlink and it works so I guess it is good.  If someone sees a potential problem doing this please feel free to let me know.